# looping and returning a array

Tags: arrays, actionscript, return

I am in need of some help. I am very new to actionscript and what I am trying to do is calculate the amount of apples from the array and then trace it in the main function. Right now I am getting an error on the return and that error is *1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number*. Now I have tried to switch out the number and string but I still get the error.

```
public class extends Sprite
{

    public function()
    {
        var fruitNames:Array = ["apple", "peach","banana","pear","guava","apple","peach"];
        var totalApples:Number = countingApples(fruitNames);
        trace("You have " + totalApples);
    }

    private function countingApples(fruitNames:Array):Number
    {
        var total:String = "apple";

        for(var i:uint=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            total += Number[i];

        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: You need to look at your `countingApples` function again, it *really* doesn't make sense. You've got a `String` which is set to "apple", then in your `for` loop you've got a `uint` which goes from 0 to 6. Then you're trying to add the `uint` to the `String` "Apple".

Answer (score 0):

```
public class extends Sprite
{

    public function()
    {
        var fruitNames:Array = ["apple", "peach","banana","pear","guava","apple","peach"];
        var totalApples:Number = countingApples(fruitNames);
        trace("You have " + totalApples);
    }

    private function countingApples(fruitNames:Array):Number
    {
        var total:uint = 0;

        var i:String = new String();
        for(i in fruitNames) {
            if (fruitNames[i] == "apple") {
                total = total + 1;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you're trying to return `total`, which is a `String`, but you've set the `countingApples` function's return type as `Number`. Here's an example which will do what you want, but I think you should try writing your own version again so that you know what's going on:

```
private function countingApples(fruitNames:Array):Number
{
    var total:uint = 0;
    var targetFruit:String = "apple";
    var totalFruit:uint = fruitNames.length;

    for(var i:uint = 0; i < totalFruit; i++)
    {
        if (fruitNames[i] == targetFruit) {
            total++;
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```